# Google Analytics ecommerce sends only last item in transaction

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track page views and transactions. The problem is that the ecommerce tracking only sends the last item added.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'); // fake code here
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': '31887',
        'revenue': '152.80',
        'shipping': '15.00',
        'currency': 'RON'
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '31887',
        'name': 'Product 1 ',
        'price': '94.90',
        'quantity': '1'
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '31887',
      'name': 'Product 2 ',
      'price': '57.90',
      'quantity': '1'
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

The code above should send 2 items but it only sends `Product 2`. Below are the requests that get sent:

[image]

As expected only the last item is being shown in the Google Analytics panel. The code seems right in every respect according to the [Ecommerce Tracking Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try specifying a unique SKU for each item -- with `ga.js` analytics, if you added multiple items with the same SKU, only the last would be recorded, just like you're seeing.

If you don't have a product SKU, use the product name.

Comment: I'm not using SKUs and the product names are all unique (so there are no conflicts there). Besides, according to the documentation the SKU is not required, just the transaction ID and product name. And also I'm using the new `analytics.js` not `ga.js`. Nevertheless, thanks for your reply

Comment: @Bogdan -- good catch, I didn't notice that SKU wasn't required in the new `analytics.js`. You might give it a try anyhow (using the product name as the SKU)... It wouldn't be the first time Google had an error in their documentation ;-)

Comment: As it turns out you were right. After posting my first comment, I decided to try sending the the product IDs as SKUs (as a workaround) and it works. Thanks you for that! (this was begining to drive me crazy)

Comment: This is worth another 20 upvotes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Removed the SKU, as it was not required, but then GA would only record one product. Added the SKU using unique product names, and it worked.Their documentation is clearly lacking, this "feature" should be bolded and highlighted in red.